# Is there a way to do a full name search in cvs history?

Tags: cvs

I'm not sure if this is a cvs bug or what it is, but I'm debugging some crusty scripts and found

> cvs history -D "-1 days" -c "s-server-moo-3"

spits out

> M 2018-03-02 19:06 +0000 user 1.71 s-server-moo-39 Network-Configs/configs == /opt/rancid/customers/CUSTA/var/Network-Configs
>
> M 2018-03-02 20:06 +0000 user 1.72 s-server-moo-39 Network-Configs/configs == /opt/rancid/customers/CUSTA/var/Network-Configs

which is not what I want, it shouldn't find "39", it should only find "3". My old crusty script is totally the number of commits and logging warnings if the total is above 8 per day, therefore if s-server-moo-38 and s-server-moo-39 each have 5 commits, I get warnings.

I know I could just grep afterwards, but this seems like a very strange way for any version control system to search. I don't see anything under `history` in the man page that says it's supposed to behave like this (or a flag to use as a workaround).

Comment: It's been a very long time since I did anything with `cvs` but i just created a tiny CVS repository for testing and AFAICT this isn't possible without post-filtering with `grep` or something.  `cvs history` does a search that matches the "file" specified on the command line with text that appears anywhere in any filename in the repo (so what the man page calls a "file" for history is actually a search pattern).   Have you considered converting to something more modern and more sane? perhaps `svn` if you're committed to cvs madness but also want new and improved.  `git` otherwise.

Comment: ps: i didn't think anyone still actually used `cvs`.

Comment: btw, i tried obvious things like appending a `$` to the end of the filename, but it seems it doesn't do a regex search.  google is not being helpful either - I guess cvs knowledge is one of those things that will be lost in time like tears in rain.

Comment: @cas flipping to git is the plan - I'm just trying to fix a bug. The scary part is this cvs instance is just an interface for rcs under the covers :)

Comment: I still use `rcs` for some things.  Well, strictly speaking, some of my Makefiles for sysadmin tasks still do - e.g. the Makefile in my /etc/postfix still updates the /etc/postfix/RCS repo mostly because I never bothered to git rid of it after switching to `etckeeper` & `git`, and because there's history in `RCS/*,v` that never got imported into git.